# BlackBerry Facebook jar file in eclipse

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I know this might sound a very basic question but I am having an issue in using Facebook SDK for Blackberry. I have downloaded the latest one 0.8.25. I have imported them in my eclipse and they are present in the referenced libraries. I have a game app where I want the users to login using their facebook account. Which class contains the code for logging in? Are the jar files implementable or they are just for reference? I have read forums posts where users say that they executed Strawberry program but I can no where find any executable source code. Kindly please let me know how do I create a login page for BlackBerry using its SDK. I did go through another link of Sample Code [here](http://www.baskoro.org/facebook-blackberry-sdk/archive/sample-codes)!

Let me know which class has login code or how do i use the SDK

Comment: send me your mail id i will mail working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very basic least, you need to get an instance of the `Facebook` object and call `getCurrentUser()`.  So, for example:

```
String[] permissions = new String[] { Facebook.Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS };
Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(new ApplicationSettings(myNextUrl, myAppId, myAppSecret, permissions));
User fbUser = fb.getCurrentUser();
```

The code in the library will handle all of the details like getting the user to login to facebook account and accept the requested permissions and so on.  You'll want to wrap that all in a try/except to catch `FacebookException` for error conditions (e.g. user refuses your request).